# The app folder is copied twice into my docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I'm trying to dockerize a fastapi application. I'm using a dockerfile as well as a docker-compose-yml file to setting up my image and containers. the problem is that the app folder is copied twice during build.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /usr/

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /usr/src/

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update \
    && apt-get -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib python3 python3-pip libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev mlocate \
    && updatedb \
    && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install fastapi uvicorn facebook-scraper pytest requests asyncpg databases psycopg2-binary SQLAlchemy
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./src
    command: |
      bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000'
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://hello_fastapi:hello_fastapi@db/facebook_posts
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_fastapi
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_fastapi
      - POSTGRES_DB=facebook_posts

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

When I connect to the container through CLI, the tree functions returns this:

```
.
|-- Dockerfile
|-- app
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- app
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- api
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- crud.py
|   |   |   |-- models.py
|   |   |   `-- posts.py
|   |   |-- db.py
|   |   `-- main.py
|   `-- requirements.txt
`-- requirements.txt
```

As you can see, the app folder is copied twice. Even though it should return this:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    ├── app
    │   ├── api
    │   │   ├── crud.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   └── posts.py
    │   ├── db.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main.py
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── requirements.txt
```

Comment: The `volumes:` block in your Compose setup is injecting a second copy of the application code that's potentially different from what's built into the image.  You should be able to delete it safely.

Comment: @DavidMaze how should I modify it? I'm sorry but I'm kinda new to docker

Comment: Just delete it.  You also don't need the obsolete `expose:` option and can delete that as well.  It's better form to put a default `CMD` in your image (which can automatically inject a `sh -c` wrapper for you) than to only have a Compose `command:` override.